# Formatting Table Using esttab

Tags: format, stata, tabular

I am able to create most of what I want: two oneway tabulations (reporting cumulative percentages) side-by-side in the same table. This is well and good, but I need some help with the formatting. A toy example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
eststo a: estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==0
eststo b: estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==1
esttab, cells("cumpct(fmt(2))") ///
    varlabels("a" "b")      ///
    nonumber nomtitle noobs ///
    collabels("a" "b")
```

This produces the following:

```
--------------------------------------
                        a            a
--------------------------------------
1                    4.17             
2                   20.83             
3                   77.08        14.29
4                   95.83        57.14
5                  100.00       100.00
Total                                 
--------------------------------------
```

How can I:

1. Get rid of the total line and
2. Make the column labels different names? I would like the second column to be called `b`, not `a`. I played around with different variations of the contents inside collabels (`a b`, `"a b"`, `""a" "b""`), but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one of these should do the trick:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
qui eststo a: estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==0
qui eststo b: estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==1
esttab, cells("cumpct(fmt(2))") ///
    nonumber mtitles("a" "b") nodepvars noobs drop(Total) collabels(none)

eststo clear
qui eststo a, title("a"): estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==0
qui eststo b, title("b"): estpost tabulate rep78 if foreign==1
esttab, cells("cumpct(fmt(2))") ///
    nonumber mtitles nodepvars noobs drop(Total) collabels(none)
```

I prefer the second syntax, since I like to name models near where I estimate them.

Both will produce something that looks like:

```
--------------------------------------
                        a            b
--------------------------------------
1                    4.17             
2                   20.83             
3                   77.08        14.29
4                   95.83        57.14
5                  100.00       100.00
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there an analogue to `eqlabels(, lhs("Repair Rec."))`? I would like to write something above the 1,...5 column.

Comment: @bill999 Try `esttab, cells("cumpct(fmt(2))") mlabels(, lhs("Repair Record")) varwidth(15) collabels(none) nonumber nodepvars noobs drop(Total)  noisily`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to take away the title labeling, though (I think that the reason "a" and "b" show up as column labels is that the eststo estimates are named "a" and "b"). Is there anyway to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: @bill999 Not entirely sure what you mean. Why don't you start a second question where you edit the output to be what you want to see?

Comment: @bill999 Had a bit of coffee and understood, I think. Try `mlabels("AAA" "BBB", lhs("Repair Record"))`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I was unclear. That works now. Am I correct to understand it to be the case that `mlabels` overrules `mtitles`? Which means that if one wants to have a `Repair Record`-type label, then it is useless to use the `title("a")` in `eststo`. And instead need to put everything into `mlabels`?

Comment: I think you could use both, but they would be on different lines, which would be undesirable.

Comment: @bill999 I was wrong above, so let me clarify. The way I understand it now, mlabel() is an `estout` option and mtitle() is an `esttab` option. `esttab` is just a wrapper for `estout` with more limited but simplified syntax, and  `estout` options take precedence over `esttab` options when they confilct. lhs() only works with mlabels(), eqlabels(), and collabels(). But you can get a Repair Record-type label, with a title from `eststo` with `mlabels(, lhs("Repair Record")) varwidth(15) mtitles` since in this case they don't  interfere.

Comment: I got it to work with just one minor tweak: I added the `title` option within `mlabels`: `mlabels(, lhs("Repair Record") title)`.